# My head pointer appears null though Im clearly assigning it c++

Tags: c++, pointers, nullptr

Basically I'm trying to get this function to work, its functionally a linked list but with node named ticket. Getting an error "head is nullptr" even though its outputting that ive assigned head (cout statements were called).

Anyways here is my flight.cpp

```
Flight::Flight() {
    head = NULL;
}
Flight::Flight(ticket* input) {
    head = input;
}
void Flight::printTicket() {
    ticket* iterator = head;
    while (iterator->next != NULL) {
        std::cout << iterator->name << std::endl;
    }
}


//00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
ticket* Flight::findSpot(ticket* t) { //returns the ticket before where the new ticket needs to be inserted
    std::string name = t->name;
    ticket* iterator = head;

    while (iterator->next != NULL) {
        if (isBefore(iterator->name, name)) {
            iterator = iterator->next;
        }
        return iterator;
    }
    std::cout << "\nFIND SPOT DID NOT WORK\n";
    return t;
}
void Flight::addTicket(std::string inName) {
    std::cout << "4 ";
    ticket *tmp = ( inName, NULL);
    std::cout << "5 ";
    if (head == NULL) {
        std::cout << "1, ";
        head = tmp;
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "2, ";
        ticket* after = findSpot(tmp);
        ticket* before = after->next;
        after->next = tmp;
        tmp->next = before;
    }
}
//00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000




std::string Flight::tolowercase(std::string input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
        if (input[i] < 97) {
            input[i] = (input[i] + 32);
        }
    }
    return input;
}
bool Flight::isBefore(std::string input1, std::string input2) {
    input1 = tolowercase(input1);
    input2 = tolowercase(input2);

    for (int i = 0; (i < input1.size() && i < input2.size()); i++) {
        if (input1[i] < input2[i]) return true;
        else if (input2[i] < input1[i]) return false;
    }
    std::cout << "ISBEFORE IS BROKEN";
    return false;
}
```

Flight.h

```
struct ticket {
    std::string name = "";
    ticket *next = NULL;
};


class Flight {
private:
    ticket* head;

    ticket* findSpot(ticket* t);

    //converts strings to lower case to allow better comparing
    std::string tolowercase(std::string input);
    bool isBefore(std::string input1, std::string input2);

public:
    Flight();
    Flight(ticket * input);
    void printTicket();
    void addTicket(std::string inName);

};
```

And my source.cpp

```
int main() {
    std::cout << "Hey!";
    Flight james = Flight();
    std::cout << "Hahaha!";
    std::string jaaems = "Jaems";
    james.addTicket(jaaems);
    james.addTicket("hahahaha");
    james.addTicket("hopefullythisworks");
    std::cout << "Made it!";
    james.printTicket();


    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone have any insight on this? Ive been ripping my hair out over this and am at the end of my wits as to why its null. I could not find an answer that I understood in any other threads, and this is my last resort. If anyone can help I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Have you tried to use a debugger?

Comment: What's up with `ticket *tmp = ( inName, NULL);`?

Comment: It depends, I feel as if I am woefully under-educated on debugging, however I did insert break points in the offending code. the error is thrown during the print statement, and the head == null if statement is called each time .addticke() is called. So I would imagine thats where the problem is if any, I should probably include that info in my main post

Comment: @kerrekSB It initializes a ticket with a null next variable. As more tickets are added next is assigned

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: What do you think `ticket *tmp = ( inName, NULL);` does? (Hint: It's the same as `ticket *tmp = NULL;`.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Does it? what should I initialize the next pointer to then? I feel like it must be null.

Comment: @NotYourDuck Abandon this and look at the [STL containers library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)?

Comment: @rawn, sorry this is for a class. So id doubt my professor would go for that, also its due at 9am, which is where the hair-pulling part comes to play.

Comment: @NotYourDuck I think you mean to make `tmp` point to a new `ticket` you are creating at this point.  But you didn't write any code to create such a ticket. You have some false impression that `(inName, NULL)` corresponds to the two members of a `ticket`.

Comment: Shouldnt it create the ticket at tmp = new ticket(args)? I understand I am assigning next to null but in addticket it does give a value to next at tmp->next = before.

Answer (score 0):

Proper way to initialize `ticket` is:

```
ticket *tmp = new ticket(inName, NULL);
```

or

```
ticket tmp = ticket(inName, NULL);
head = &tmp;
```

**Update:**

And you need to change your `ticket` declaration to include constructor:

```
struct ticket {
    std::string name;
    ticket *next;
    ticket(std::string aname, ticket *anext) {
       name = aname;
       next = anext;
    } 
};
```

or if you do not want to add constructor, just initialize it like this:

```
ticket tmp = {inName, NULL};
head = &tmp;
```

Comment: Its giving me an error saying that it doesnt match the argument list, apparently it wants my ticket pointer in the struct to be initialized to an int instead of a pointer to ticket, confused yet again /:

Comment: What did you change your code to? `ticket *tmp = new ticket(inName, NULL);`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes, and just to be sure I copy/pasted it to the same result. It says that the arguments should be std::string, int. This makes no sense to me, as the struct doesnt have any int variables, does a pointer boil down to an int value?

Comment: `ticket` does not have any constructor accepting 2 arguments; this answer is completely wrong